# Jquery contains selector, regex

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, contains

This is my code: 
Let's say that `name` is set to `john`

```
$("#first_table").append($('#second_table').find("tr:contains(" + name + ")"));
```

Basically I have 2 tables on my website. I would like to move elements from first to second, but only if they match completely. How can i do that?

Now if I have (for example) `john` `john #1`, `john #2` in my table, they would all be moved. I would only like to move `john` and leave `john #1` and `john #2`
Thanks!
EDIT: 
I would like the code to work to match the variable `name` EXACTLY. 
So if `name` is `JOHN` it must only get `JOHN`. If it's `JOHN #1`, it must only get `JOHN #1` and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every name case is valid to `:contains(" + name +")` statement, it matches all of them.

Try this, with a `:not` to omit the one with "#"

```
$("#first_table").append($('#second_table').find("tr:contains(" + name + "):not(:contains('#'))"));
```

Update:

If you want to be precise about the values inside. Then use something like this

```
$("#second_table tr td").each(function() {
   if($(this).text() == 'John') { 
     $(this).closest("tr").appendto($("#first_table")); //find the cotaining tr and append to another table
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
One more thing - how can I then get john #2 for example?
I would like the code to work to match the variable name EXACTLY. 
So if name is JOHN it must only get JOHN. If it's JOHN #1, it must only get JOHN #1 and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case of missing quotes. Try adding single quotes around `name` as shown below.

```
$("#first_table").append($('#second_table').find("tr:contains('" + name + "')"));
```

Comment: @JernejPangeršič, are you sure there isn't anything else affecting the selector, because `John A` doesn't contain `John B`, so both the entries shouldn't move. Can you make sure `name` is definitely `John A`, and not `John`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I explained it wrong. I edited the original post, take a look at it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.